# Проект собранный в Visual Studio 2015 требует MSVCR110D.dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Скачал [демо CMU Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/#windows) для Windows.

У меня установлена Visual Studio Community 2015.

Открыл, сконвертировал в 2015 и собрал оба солюшена в этой Visual Studio. Собралось без ошибок.
Однако при попытке запуска приложения выдаётся сообщение:
"Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует MSVCR110D.dll".
Насколько я понимаю, это dll от Visual Studio 2012. Как проект собираемый в 2015 может зависеть от dll из 2012?

Посмотрел настройки всех проектов - в линкере нигде явно не указаны зависимости от этой dll.

На всякий случай поменял Runtime Library с Multithreaded Debug DLL на Multithreaded Debug во всех проектах - это не помогло. Исполняемый файл всё-равно требует MSVCR110D.dll.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело и где ещё можно поискать причину этой проблемы?

ОС: Windows 8.1

Comment: Следует взять dependency walker или его аналог, и поглядеть, какой именно бинарь зависит от MSVCR110D.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, при использовании компилятора MSVC зависимость от библиотеки может быть прописана не только в настройках линкера, но и прямо в исходном коде через `#pragma comment(lib, ...`

Во-вторых, если ваш проект линкует в себя какие-то уже скомпилированные библиотеки, то эта зависимость может быть прописана в них и, соответственно, унаследована из них.

Comment: Первое наверное маловероятно, а вот второе весьма...